# Passing props to screens

Tags: react-native

How do I pass a prop to a screen via navigation? I am trying the following:

```
navigation.push('User', {auth_user: true});
```

But the prop doesn't propagate to the functional components where the screen is rendered. What is the proper way to pass a prop to a screen? My app module:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Logout" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="User" component={UserDetailScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

UserDetailScreen.js:

```
export default class UserDetailScreen extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <User auth_user={this.props.auth_user} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: How do try to access the param in `User ` screen?

Comment: this.props.auth_user

Answer (score 1):

To get a param passed to a screen in `react-navigation` v5 you would use:

in a functional component:

`const auth_user = props.route.params.auth_user;`

in a class component:

`const auth_user = this.props.route.params.auth_user;`